# How to use groupby groups in for loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to use grouped dataframe in for loop but in every iteration i get result of last group. i am using this piece of code

```
dfx=[]
grouped=df.groupby('x')
for items,df in grouped:
    x=np.mean(df['y'])
    dfx.append(x)
final=pd.concat(dfx)
```

the problem is this code only giving result of last group everytime

Comment: works fine on my side

Comment: here still getting last group results

Comment: First, you redefine `df` in the loop. Change `df` in `for items,df in grouped:` to something else. Second, `x` is a number, and `dfx` is a list of numbers. You cannot apply `concat` to a list of numbers. Third, why not do `df.groupby('x').mean()`?